# Hide image carousel prev/next arrows when overlay is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) slider and would like to hide the arrow when the "+" icon is clicked and the arrows are shown when the overlay is disabled.

The class of the arrows is `.flickity-prev-next-button`. I would like to add a `display:none;` css property when the button is clicked.

What's the best way of achieving this? The function to open and close the overlay is listed below. I tried adding `$(".flickity-prev-next-button").css("display", "none");`to the if statement but no luck unfortunately.

```
       function openNav() {
      // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
      if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
        // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
$(".flickity-prev-next-button").css("display", "none");
      } else {
        // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
        closeNav();
      }
        function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
    }
    }
```

Here's a code snippet for your reference.

```js
function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";

  } else {

    // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
    closeNav();
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#transformicon {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Import zero-transformicon build bundle -->
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">
<div id="transformicon">
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()">

  </zero-transformicon>
</div>

<div class="main-carousel js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "cellAlign": "left","contain": true,"wrapAround":true,"draggable":true,"arrowShape":"M62.5 0l3.6 2.1L38.7 50l27.4 47.9-3.6 2.1-28.6-50L62.5 0z"
}'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zVBkvKZ/fever-t-shirt-front.jpg" alt="fever-t-shirt-front" border="0"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zVBkvKZ/fever-t-shirt-front.jpg" alt="fever-t-shirt-front" border="0"></div>
</div>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you tried:

```
$(".flickity-prev-next-button").css("display", "none");
```

worked for me, however you probably want to use

```
$('.flickity-prev-next-button').toggle();
```

so that the nav buttons reappear when the overlay is closed.

```js
function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  $('.flickity-prev-next-button').toggle();
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";

  } else {

    // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
    closeNav();
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
.main-carousel {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#transformicon {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Import zero-transformicon build bundle -->
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">
<div id="transformicon">
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()">

  </zero-transformicon>
</div>

<div class="main-carousel js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "cellAlign": "left","contain": true,"wrapAround":true,"draggable":true,"arrowShape":"M62.5 0l3.6 2.1L38.7 50l27.4 47.9-3.6 2.1-28.6-50L62.5 0z"
}'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zVBkvKZ/fever-t-shirt-front.jpg" alt="fever-t-shirt-front" border="0"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zVBkvKZ/fever-t-shirt-front.jpg" alt="fever-t-shirt-front" border="0"></div>
</div>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue

Comment: The toggle property is a great idea. You have saved me tons of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can use  $(".flickity-button").css('display','none');

  function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
  // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  $(".flickity-button").css('display','none');
  } else {

   // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
   closeNav();
 }

  function closeNav() {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
     $(".flickity-button").css('display','block');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,Vikash. I'm new to javascript and I've been scratching my head on why this was not working in the first place. I didn't add the jquery plugin to my page. Rookie error.